# Why does chinese characters scrambled in screen in progress application?

Tags: openedge

> in our application,we have an utility to generate the file in pdf format but when i do that i see some chinese characters are scrambled in the screen.What could be the reason?

Comment: You need to provide more info about your application and environment. Is it windows/linux/unix. Version of Progress? Character, web, .net-client, graphical client etc? Has it always been like this or is there any recent changes leading up to it. Attach a screen shot if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF is a binary file format.  If you view such a file on the screen it is normal for gibberish characters to appear.

Comment: Tom,is there anything we can do to avoid this?

Comment: Don't view binary files in a terminal window?  If you want to view a PDF file you need to use a PDF reader of some sort.  How you do that depends entirely on what your environment is.

Comment: PDF files are text files. They can contain binary streams for fonts or image data, these are base64 encoded. If you are seeing some strange characters one of your text streams probably contains characters that are invalid with the selected encoding.

Comment: Sort of -- but, by convention, the 2nd line usually contains a comment with the high order bits set in order to convince email and so forth to treat the file as binary.  Which is probably what triggers gibberish when displaying to the screen.